# KDE - How to configure shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, plasma, plasma-5

In Ubuntu I got the following shortcuts:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to Maximize Window

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to Minimize Window

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to Move Window

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to minimize all windows and show desktop

I want to do the same in KDE (Kubuntu) but in settings there's no way to do that. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Go to

```
System Settings > Workspace > Shortcuts > Global Keyboard shortcuts
```

In `KDE component` choose `KWin` and scroll down through
the list.
You will find the options `Minimize Window`, `Maximize Window`,`Move Window` and `Show Desktop`. Click in the `Global`-columne right to the desired action, a small menu pops up and you can enter the desired shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

KDE has a huge number of features and customisation options. You have to first decide what kind of shortcut you want to use. Try to look at the global shortcuts application. You should be able to set it there.